# Opentelemetry PHP traces doesn't shows on cross app

Tags: php, open-telemetry, apm, otel

I'm implementing OpenTelemetry for application monitoring. My application uses .NET for the backend and PHP for the front end, and everything is configured using the OpenTelemetry auto-instrumentation. For .NET I can see all the traces between different .NET applications combined into the same span. But I can't see the PHP traces on the same span as backend when it sends a request to the backend. I can only see the PHP traces as their own span. Just wondering if there is a way to combine those traces (frontend and backend)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have all of the correct packages installed to enable context propagation, which should link your PHP and .NET spans together in Jaeger.

The opentelemetry-auto-psr18 package which you have installed does that for you. You should check that when you make a request from PHP to your .NET backend, that you are using the PSR-18 client's `sendRequest` method. Many HTTP clients support PSR-18 but also provide other methods such as `get`, `post` etc, and those might not use `sendRequest` internally.